# php repeat loop Infinite

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Im trying to achieve something simple like repeating colors for each element.

Here is my function:

```
function colors() {
   $colorArray = array('#f44336', '#9c27b0', '#e91e63');
   return $colorArray[array_rand($colorArray)];
}



<ul>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="color:<?php echo colors(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
</ul>
```

this works fine, but I would like not to have random colors, instead keep repeating first 3 colors from array. I could have as many as 500 items, so the loop must be able to run infinite.

Comment: Which loop?....

Comment: idk what you want to do? more than 3 colours? infinity amount of list items?

Comment: See please [ask] and modify your question.

Comment: @Sebastian Tkaczyk I want 3 colors but infinite number of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alternate the three colors then you need to keep a record of the last color used. Here is a simple modification to your function requiring the use of a `static` variable:

```
function colors() {
    static $colorCounter = -1;
    $colorArray = array('#f44336', '#9c27b0', '#e91e63');
    $colorCounter++;
    return $colorArray[$colorCounter % count($colorArray)];
}
```

Here is the example output (three colors repeated infinitely):
https://eval.in/859522

Comment: As long as you're setting the counter as a global variable, why not make the colors global as well to avoid the reassignment on each call?

Comment: I was going for the least amount of changes to the OPs code but that's a good point.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: Consider using a `static` variable instead - `function colors() {static $counter = 0; ... }` - avoids polluting global scope.

Comment: Great suggestion @NiettheDarkAbsol - updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS.

```
li:nth-child(3n+1) {color: #f44336;}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {color: #9c27b0;}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {color: #e91e63;}
```

Much cleaner :p

Comment: A great CSS alternative if the OP can live without IE8 support.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable to store the index each time it is used. Increment that variable during each iteration -- if greater than the count of the array return to zero.

```
// Create a global variable
$current_color = -1;  

function colors() {
    // Access global var
    global $current_color;  
    // Array of colors
    $colorArray = array('#f44336', '#9c27b0', '#e91e63');  
    // Increment global var 
    $current_color++;  
    // Return to zero if var is greater than the count of your array
    $current_color = ( $current_color < count( $colorArray ) ) ? $current_color : 0;  
    // Return color
    return $colorArray[$current_color]; 
}
```

Comment: @neuromatter **If your global doesn't start at -1 you will start with the second color.**

Answer (score 0):

Any excuse to have fun with [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php)

```
<?php
class Colors
{
    private $infinite;

    public function __construct(array $colors)
    {
        $this->infinite = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($colors));
        $this->infinite->rewind();
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $return = $this->infinite->current();
        $this->infinite->next();

        return $return;
    }
}

$colors = new Colors(['#111', '#222', '#333']);
```

Just call `echo $colors->get()` whenever you want a color. See https://eval.in/859523